# Clicking on "Join" link in TripAdvisor does not work!

Tags: help, https

Total Tor newbie here. I have Tor Bundle with Tor Browser 4.5-alpha-1.

I have a problem with certain links - nothing happens at all.
As an example, the Join link on www.tripadvisor.com.
I assume it is because it links to a HTTPS URL but isn't Tor supposed to handle that?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

That link requires JavaScript. Enable it and it should work. Alternatively just visit the link https://www.tripadvisor.com/Register.

Also, HTTPS works fine on Tor. TBB actually has HTTPS Everywhere installed which automatically uses https on all known sites to support HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you but that link just redirects me back to tripadvisor.com. I also tried enabling javascript (I even enabled all scripts), also no go.

Answer (score 0):

Tor Bundle with Tor Browser 4.5-alpha-1 is an experimental package. There maybe number of problems with that package. This is way it is called alpha. It maybe best to use a stable version of Tor package at this stage. When you become more familiar with Tor, you may consider an experimental software like an alpha version.